# Removing line break from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file for which each line is supposed to finish by at geographical coordinate (so a number). Somehow some line breaks pollute some lines so i would like to remove them.

Since some other lines are ok the plan is to remove the line breaks and add a space instead at the end of the lines of my csv file, every time a line doesnt finish by a number or a "None" (value we use when we could not get the coordinate.).

Instead of:

```
www.audiar.org,www.epfbretagne.fr,Agence
d'urbanisme,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219
www.audiar.org,www.fnau.org,Agence
d'urbanisme,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219,None,None
```

I need to get this:

```
www.audiar.org,www.epfbretagne.fr,Agence d'urbanisme,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219
www.audiar.org,www.fnau.org,Agence d'urbanisme,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219,None,None
```

But i must admit i have no idea how to achieve that... I checked some other posts close to my problem. Solutions seem to be using sed but i dont have a linux here (and not sure to understand the syntax) and i'm a poor poor python user...

Comment: read two lines, concatenate them and write in new file as one line, next read another two lines, concatenate and write in new file as one line, etc.

Comment: or read one line, if it is OK then write it in new file, if it not OK then read next line and concatenate to first and write it in new file. And do it again with rest of file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two consecutive lines:

```
>>> line1 = 'www.audiar.org,www.epfbretagne.fr,Agence'
>>> line2 = "d'urbanisme,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219,-1.68186449144,48.1119791219"
```

Attempt to interpret the last part of the first line as a number or `None`. If it fails, concatenate the next line to it:

```
import ast

last_part = line1.rsplit(',', 1)[1]  # == 'Agence'

try:
    data = ast.literal_eval(last_part)
except:
    # this line is incorrect
    output = line1 + ' ' + line2
else:
    if isinstance(data, float) or data is None:
        output = line1 # everything is OK
    else:
        raise ValueError("Malformed data!")

# `output` is one processed line
```

Then move `line2` to `line1` and read a new line into `line2`. If the two lines were concatenated, special handling may be required, because the "error" (a line *not* ending with a float or `None`) may continue on `line2`. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but i can't. I was no clear enough i guess. Some lines in the file are good. So i need to select the wrong ones. The wrong lines are the one that doesnt end by a number or 'None'.

Comment: Ok thanks, looks neat. Now i just need to find out how to apply that to my 3000+ lines ^^ (Elie Kakou for ever <3 !)